# How to change from negative number to zero in Swift

Tags: swift, unsigned-long-long-int, negative-zero

I have `Double` data type, cause I need result with floating number, but if my result is negative, it broke all my algorithm. Is there maybe a unsigned data type with floating point?

[image]

Comment: You should share some code, perhaps a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue. Also, you might want to clarify "broke" (e.g. got a result different than you expected? crashed? etc.; and if it crashed, share the precise error message).

Comment: Using an unsigned float data type (if it existed) wouldn't help. It would immediately crash when you give it a negative. value. You have a deeper underlying logic issue.

Answer (score 40):

Use `max` to limit numbers from going below zero:

```
let posOrZero = max(possiblyNegative, 0)
```

If `possiblyNegative` is above zero, it's going to be the result of `max`; Otherwise, zero is returned.

Comment: You deserve an upvote just for being able to decipher the question